# Swap two columns in spark sql dataframe and remove duplicates

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark

I am using spark 1.6 and python 2.7 and I have a spark dataframe like below:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
        ("ab", "bc"),
        ("bc", "cd"),
        ("cd", "ab"),
        ("bc", "ab"),
        ("cd", "bc"),
        ("ab", "cd"),
    ], ["col1", "col2"])
```

This dataframe contains the vertex of a graph as "col1" to "col2". What I am trying to do is to remove the duplicate pairs of col1 and col2.
What my approach is, compare the col1 and col2, if col2 < col1 then swap the columns and then perform distinct operation.

After the operations, the result should be:

```
+------------+
| col1  col2 |
+------------+
|  ab   bc   |
|  bc   cd   |
|  cd   ab   |
+------------+
```

Basically, I am trying to create a graph with only directed edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do the following

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
finaldf = df.withColumn('col1_1', F.when(df.col2 < df.col1, df.col2).otherwise(df.col1)) \
    .withColumn('col2_1', F.when(df.col2 < df.col1, df.col1).otherwise(df.col2))\

finaldf.select(finaldf.col1_1.alias("col1"), finaldf.col2_1.alias("col2")).distinct().show()
```

What is done here is *two new columns are created* applying the `col2 < col1` logic and finally `select`ing the `distincts`.

Comment: Thanks it is working.Would it be efficient if the record set contains 300 million records?

Comment: yes @user1590716 I guess so :) thanks for the acceptance